# How to use GNOME3 with Compiz

Tags: compiz, gnome

I choose in LightDM gnome-classic session.

I launched gnome3 with the classic style (the fallback). But compiz doesn't work.

If I execute `compiz --replace` compiz starts working.

But how enable automatic loading of compiz? If I add compiz to autostart in gnome starting takes lot of time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable compiz in Gnome Classic?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session` in key `RequiredProviders` in parameter `notifications`

This parameter causes to fail loading of `gnome-classic` (which have window manager `gnome-wm`), and system try to load `gnome-fallback` (which have window manager `metacity`). I remove `notifications` parameter from `RequiredProviders` key, and my `gnome-classic` now loading with `compiz` (`gnome-wm` loads `compiz`).

Full story of solving this problem in Russian language: http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=170434.0

Comment: The disadvantage of using this method is that you cant add or customise the panels - I think you can only do this via gnome-fallback mode... unless you have any other ideas?

Comment: You mean that Alt+Button2 didnt work? I have same problem, its because of compiz, I change key binding settings in compiz-config - so now I can cutomize my gnome panels

Comment: where is compiz-config ? It is not on my 11.10 system; apt-get does not know about it. I do have Compiz Config Settings Manager (ccsm) - is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, sorry about that, I mean ccsm. Its hard to clear Alt+Button2 (or Button3, dont remember) keybind because its reset after restart, I dont know why, seems bug. The solution is to set another keybind for window menu.

Comment: Good that you wrote some things in English. I am Brazilian and for me Russian is like Chinese. Thanks for sharing text in the universal language. It seems that the parameter "notifications;" is useless in the classic gnome session...