# How do I enable compiz in Gnome Classic?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome-classic

I am running Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10.

My understanding is that **Gnome Classic** is with Compiz effects, and **Gnome Classic (No Effects)** has no Compiz.

However, when i run **Gnome Classic**, compiz does not seem to be running. If I open compiz-settings-manager, I have all my settings, but none of them are taking effect.

Is there something I need to be doing to enable Compiz in **Gnome Classic**?

---

As requested in the comments of the answers, here is the output of ~/.xsession-errors:

```
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/gnome/SessionManager interface=org.gnome.SessionManager method=Is
Inhibited
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/gnome/SessionManager interface=org.gnome.SessionManager method=Is
Inhibited
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/gnome/SessionManager interface=org.gnome.SessionManager method=Is
Inhibited
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): Starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App37
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: starting jockey-gtk.desktop: command=sh -c 'test -e /var/cache/jockey/check |
| exec jockey-gtk --check' startup-id=102cff201a509beb8813189506573089800000204500036
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: started pid:20888
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): Starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App29
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: starting update-notifier.desktop: command=update-notifier startup-id=102cff20
1a509beb88131895065698387500000204500028
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: started pid:20889
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: (pid:20888) done (status:0)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "rgba"
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
gnome-session[20450]: DEBUG(+): GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerC
hanged
`menu_proxy_module_load': update-notifier: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(update-notifier:20889): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': update-notifier: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(update-notifier:20889): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': update-notifier: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(update-notifier:20889): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': update-notifier: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(update-notifier:20889): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this problem edit this file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session
```

and replace this line:

```
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;
```

with this one:

```
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
```

Then just logout and log back in and it should work fine.
This solved the problem in my case.

**EDIT 1:**

1) to access the gnome panel menu now you need to use **"windows key + alt + right click"** on panels instead of **"alt + right click"**

2) another issue might be **"alt + tab"** but you just need to reassign it in **Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts**

**EDIT 2:**

3) after **system updates** related to **GTK or gnome** you might need to reinstall any "custom" drivers for your graphics card,  for e.g. NVIDIA linux driver

Comment: Yes works but loose the ALT function see my comment below

Comment: instead of "alt + right click" on panel use "windows key + alt + right click" and it works fine then :) another issue might be "alt + tab" but you just need to reassign it in Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

Comment: Good find, windows key + alt does indeed work, perhaps edit your answer above to include this info

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Classic should run compiz if you have acceleration enabled (you can try to run `/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated; echo $?` and it should return 0), if it returns something else, it's probably that you don't have harware acceleration and so fallback to GNOME classic (No effects).

If no, is running `/usr/bin/gnome-wm --replace` replace your current environment with compiz ?

Comment: I get 0 when I run the first command, and when I run `/usr/bin/gnome-wm --replace`, then Compiz comes alive (yay!). However, the only thing now is that if I log out and log in again, I lose Compiz. How do I make it stick?

Comment: That's weird…  Can you check that `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session` contains: `DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm`. If so, please edit: ``/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop`, add `--debug` to the exec line and report your `~/.xsession-errors` after login.

Comment: I followed your instructions and appended the tail end of the error log to the original question. The whole file was way to long to include here. I hope that the portion I provided is sufficient. Oh, and the `DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm` line was where you said it should be.

Comment: Yes you can remove notifications and you can also change gnome-wm to compiz. The only problem then is you loose the ALT key action and can't access the panel settings

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness,

another solution that works for me is to add "/usr/bin/compiz --replace" to the GNOME startup applications via:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

I lost the Alt-RightClick functionality too (Windows+Alt-Rightclick is necessary) but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is still working.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Compiz effects frequently fail to load at startup in Ubuntu 10.04. To enable Compiz, I have to logout then login again. This usually does the trick.