# What is button5?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome-classic

I want to record my Desktop and use zoom function. I changed Zoom in shortcut to `<super>button5` and when I click Windows logo and scroll my mouse, it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's not mouse button 5 but keyboard button 5, i.e. the number key for 5 on the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XServer interprets scrollwheel as extra mouse buttons; in Compiz, it's Button4 for Wheel Up and Button5 for Wheel Down - more details [in Compiz wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM#Mouse_Buttons). This is for Compiz in Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 may differ (although I doubt it).

I assume you have set up the shortcut using CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`).
First make sure you have actually enabled the plugin you want to use for zooming.
Also, [as lgarzo suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72925/what-is-button5/72928#72928), try setting a different, non-conflict shortcut, possibly without a Super key - this key is a bit overloaded in Unity and sometimes just doesn't work for custom shortcuts.

EDIT: The problem was that Compiz wasn't actually running (see the comments below). Otherwise there's nothing wrong with Compiz zoom plugin.

Comment: Set upt alt button5, still not working... :/

Comment: You could try a different plugin - in 11.04 there are "Zoom Desktop" and "Enhanced Zoom Desktop". What plugin do you use? What is the name of the entry you've setup the shortcut for? Or better yet - could you post a screenshot of the CompizConfig window where you set this shortcut?

Comment: yes, give me two minutes.

Comment: here: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5269/screenshotat20111027214.png

Comment: I see... This should be okay, considering there are no conflicting shortcuts (which CCSM should warn you about) or that you're actually running Unity-2D :-) I know it sounds a bit Microsoft-y but have you tried to log out/in or to execute `unity --replace`? I used to have problem with Compiz not registering new plugins in Unity.

Comment: I logouted it, didn't work. I use Gnome CLassic (No effects) on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Here's the problem - in "No effects" session, Compiz is probably not running at all. You'll need to use *Gnome Classic*. If you run into problems, there are questions dealing with Compiz in Gnome Classic, see e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic and [tag:gnome-classic]

Comment: Ran it in Gnome Classic, doesn't work neither.

Comment: it works, horray :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the mouse scroll up direction.

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Button5</kbd> instead.