# Alt-Tab in Unity 2D makes app icon jiggle instead of switching

Tags: unity-2d

I'm using Unity 2D as my desktop, and it works fine most of the time, but every now and then, I try to Alt-Tab to switch to a different application, and instead of switching to that window, the launcher bar opens, and the icon of the application I was trying to switch to starts jiggling.

If I try to switch to something else, that icon starts jiggling too. If I click on the icon with the mouse, then it stops jiggling and switches to the requested window.

What is this behavior? I haven't seen any mention of jiggling icons in Unity. I don't understand the original purpose of this, and I'd like a way to fix it so that I won't have to use the mouse.

**EDIT:** I get that this is a bug, but someone must have had to code that jiggling effect. What is it used for? Is it some relic of old behavior, or something new that hasn't been implemented yet, what?

Comment: This is a bug. Report a bug against metacity on launchpad.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a bug, so there's not much you can do about that other then filing a bug report. But, you can enable the Super(Window Key) + Tab switcher which does the same thing, switches between applications. I will show you how to enable the Super Key + Tab switcher in Ubuntu 11.10.

**1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center.**
[image: Software Center]

**2. In the search box in the upper right hand corner, type in "Compiz Config Settings Manager". Click on the result for the program, then click install.**
[image]

**3. Enter your password when prompted, then press Enter.**

**4. Once the application has finished installing, open it by pressing the Super key, searching for "Compiz Config Settings Manager", and clicking the result for the program. You will see a window like the following:**
[image]

**5. Click "Ring Switcher",Then click check the checkbox to enable the plugin. Close CCSM, then press Super + Tab.**

**6. Have fun with your new switcher!**

[image]

Comment: ... but unity 2D doesnt use compiz and hence doesnt use ccsm...

Comment: Yes... why is he using Unity 2D? Could this be a bug in Unity 2D?

Comment: probably a bug - but the comment has already been made by roland (see the comments just below the question). Dont know why the OP is using Unity2D - but the question is definitely about unity2d not unity+compiz...

Comment: I know, I saw the comment. For now, this seems that this is all the OP can do, switch to Unity 3D if it kills him/her, unless there's some reason that he/she can't...

Comment: To enable compiz in Unity 2D, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, my answer was converted into a comment. However, I will answer your edit.

The jiggling behaviour is intended to indicate that an application needs your attention, but is not in focus. This is how it works in Unity 3D, and, when everything is in working order, in Unity 2D as well. Probably what is happening is that the application is being given "focus" but not being raised.