# Compiz no longer auto starts on login

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome-classic

When I first installed Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome-Classic, Compiz wouldn't run, and so I solved it by [asking here on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic).

However, after the most recent set of updates a couple days ago, Compiz no longer automatically starts when I boot up and log in.

If I simply reload the window manager, then Compiz starts.

How can I get Compiz to start automatically?

---

Update: output of ~/.xsession-errors:

```
(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31457708, 751, 0

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31457708, 928, 0

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31457956, 751, 0

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31457956, 928, 0

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31458022, 751, 0

** (gnome-panel:2970): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 31458022, 928, 0

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image: ass
ertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM (image_menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_menu_item_get_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_M
ENU_ITEM (menu_item)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGE
T (widget)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTA
INER (container)' failed

(nautilus:2985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: find_menu_position: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHE
LL (menushell)' failed
** (process:3159): DEBUG: Telepathy Indicator started

** (gnome-screensaver:3160): WARNING **: screensaver already running in this ses
sion
```

Comment: Is there any relevant messages in `~/.xsession-errors` when this problem occurs?

Comment: I've added the output of ~/.xsession-errors into the question. It is the tail end of the file, as it was too long to reproduce fully.

Comment: I had this problem too. I had to redo the changes to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session` again.

Comment: @Anonymous: That worked. If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. I had to redo the changes to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session` again.