# Is it possible to use compiz cube in Gnome Classic?

Tags: compiz, gnome-classic, cube

I was wondering if the compiz cube works in gnome classic too?
And if yes, how shall I install it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work fine.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then open the settings manager, find cube and enable. You might have to disable a few other effects which conflict.

Comment: That's the part that I am afraid of....I screwed up big time Ubuntu a few month ago because of that :D