# Gnome Shell keeps falling back to classic desktop when trying to enable it on an Optimus laptop

Tags: gnome, nvidia-optimus

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 beta, and after installing the gnome-shell each time before i log in, when I select Gnome desktop, I get the gnome backfall (classic) desktop.

I also noticed that I cannot enable compiz, (I could with the 10.10 version), I dont know if it has something to do with the drivers.

I have a intel i3 processor

Comment: What's your graphics card? If there is any proprietary graphics driver, do you have enabled it?

Comment: 1, Have you installed mutter?, 2.Gnome Shell can possibly be used with Compiz though it's not the correct way for the Shell to work it uses Mutter, 3.In my experience Gnome Shell fails to load with an AMD graphics card.

Comment: Almost certainly something wrong with your graphics card configuration.  It is not enabling compositing, because your graphics driver is either missing or not configured properly.

Comment: My computer has a Nvidia GT325M with Nvidia Optimus, but never enabled the propietary graphics (neither when I had ubuntu 10.10 & compiz & shell working) and being working always with the I3 internal graphics procesor wich has been always enough for my work in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have just installed mutter and restarted, but still GNOME SHELL not starting, going to the FALLBACK version directly.

Comment: please have a look at my answer here: [how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68711/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-gnome-classic/68884#68884) it is quite possible you are having the same problem which was introduced in Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue installing bumblebee, after the restart everything is working correctly, Shell & Compiz on Gnome Classic

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/bumblebee
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an optimus based laptop, going to the Ubuntu Software Center and removing the "NVidia binary X.Org driver ('current' driver)" may solve the problem.

Comment: I dont have that driver installed